# перенос с ms sql в mysql pyt

Tags: python, sql-server, mysqli, python-3.8

Делаю перенос некоторых полей с ms sql в my sql на python. И **надо делать именно на python** ни на чем больше

```
cur_my = conn_my.cursor()
cur_ms = conn_ms.cursor()
cur_ms.execute("SELECT item_id, id_group FROM items")
for row in cur_ms.fetchall():
    cur_my.execute("INSERT INTO items_in_dbo (item_id,  id_group) VALUES (%s,%s)", ('item_id','id_group'))
conn_my.commit()


conn_ms.close()
conn_my.close()
```

Но переносит почему то так, подскажите в чем дело

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPD

```
for row in cur_ms.fetchall():
    print(row) 
    cur_my.execute("INSERT INTO items_in_dbo (item_id,  id_group) VALUES ('%s','%s')"% (row[0][0],row[0][1]))
conn_my.commit()
```

но выдает теперь, может ли быть дело в кодировке?? там varchar(255) и могут быть поля с текстом типо _яяяяяяя123123 и id_group INT

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы зачем-то в цикле `print(row)` поставили, но не поделились, что там печатается. Кажется, не помешало бы знать, как именно выглядит типичное значение, хранящееся в `row`. Ну ладно...

`row` - это котеж из данных полей текущей строки. `row[0]` - это значение первого поля (судя по всему - `item_id`) текущей строки. Например, как вы приводите в вопросе `"_яяяяяяя123123"`.

Тогда

- `row[0][0]` - первый символ, подчеркивание
- `row[0][1]` второй символ, буква "я", которую СУБД неявно преобразует в ноль

Если каждый `item_id` начинается именно с подчеркивания, то и результат выглядит абсолютно предсказуемым: в первый столбец записались символы подчеркивания, во второй - нули.

Что нужно, так это скорее всего - `(row[0], row[1])`.
Причем не подставлять это прямо в строку, это пагубная небезопасная практика.

Лучше так (за подробностями можно ознакомиться с документацией на используемую библиотеку):

```
cur_my.execute(
    "INSERT INTO items_in_dbo (item_id,  id_group) VALUES (%s, %s)",
    (row[0], row[1])
)
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое, а как решить проблему с кодировкой?  _Ðî000000659   вот такие символы пришли     [item_id] varchar(255) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS  NOT NULL,    это в ms sql  а в mysql  utf8 general ci

Comment: Задавайте новый вопрос и включайте в него все подробности, посмотрим